# How to delete a Task (Row) with Interop.MSProject

Tags: c#, interop, ms-project

I'm trying to use Interop.MSProject with C# to do something that conceptually, should be the simiplest thing in the world to do.  However, I am having some trouble with it's cryptic api which has minimal documentation.  All I wish to do is to find a row that contains a specific string in one of it's columns (cell) and remove that row.  After I've done that, I just want to display the modified project file so that the user has the option to save it.  Here is what I've tried:

```
MSProject.Application app = new MSProject.Application();
app.FileOpenEx(
    filePath,
    false,
    Type.Missing,
    Type.Missing,
    Type.Missing,
    Type.Missing,
    Type.Missing,
    Type.Missing,
    Type.Missing,
    Type.Missing,
    Type.Missing,
    MSProject.PjPoolOpen.pjPoolReadWrite,
    Type.Missing,
    Type.Missing,
    Type.Missing,
    Type.Missing,
    Type.Missing);

foreach(MSProject.Task task in proj.Tasks)
{
    if (task == null) continue;
    string cellValue = task.OutlineCode3;
    if (cellValue == searchString)
       task.Delete();
}  

app.Visible = true;
```

It seems as though task.Delete is not working.  I've even tried to generalize this code to the following:

```
foreach (MSProject.Task task in proj.Tasks)
   task.Delete()
```

and this did not work either.  Does anyone know a way that I can remove a task or a row base on a value in one of the rows cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same conundrum yesterday.

Your approach is correct but it doesn't work because the tasks are Index-based. This is more obvious in a straight for loop.

If you have 10 tasks and delete one, let's say number 5, now the next task (6) is now 5 but your loop will try to delete 6 which is now 7. This will mess everything up.

If you want to delete all tasks you should do something like:

```
// Task Indexes are 1-based not 0-based
for(int i = 1; i <= proj.Tasks.Count; i++) {
    proj.Tasks[i].Delete();
    i--;
}
```

Following this train of thought let's apply this to a foreach loop

```
foreach(Task t in tasksToDelete) {
    proj.Tasks[proj.GetTaskIndexByGuid(t.Guid)].Delete();
}
```

Why am I using GetTaskIndexByGuid? It seems that the Index property of each task if not properly (or immeadiately) updated when you delete a task but I found that using GetTaskIndexByGuid always returns the correct index.

Hope it helps